# Python: Using multiple IPV4Network test addresses in List comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I'm trying to validate a particular IP address whether if or not it exists in the ipaddress.IPV4Network that I have defined.
For example , the code :

```
import ipaddress
ipv = '192.168.255.0'
ans = [str(ip1)in ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16')]
if ipv in ans:
    print('Present')
else:
    print('Not Present')
```

returns `True` since the `ipv='192.168.255.0'` is within the range of `ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16')`

returns `False` for `ipv='192.255.255.0'` , since it is out of range.

I want to do this check for multiple private IP addresses , something like:

```
ans = [str(ip1, ip2, ip3) for ip1, ip2, ip3 in (ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16'), ipaddress.IPv4Network('10.0.0.0/8'), ipaddress.IPV4Network('172.16.0.0/12'))]
```

This structure is totally wrong and not allowed in python.
Is there any efficient way to accomplish this ?

Comment: what you want is not totally clear, if you want to check the existence of more ip addresses you only need a different if/else structure

Comment: I want to validate private IP address range in a single line. Trying to accomplish it through list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

**Script**

```
import ipaddress
ip_list = ['192.168.0.0', '192.168.0.12', '192.169.255.34']
ip_result = {ip: ipaddress.ip_address(ip) in 
ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.0.0/16') for ip in ip_list}
print(ip_result)
```

**Output**

```
{'192.168.0.0': True, '192.168.0.12': True, '192.169.255.34': False}
```